# How to connect 2 webcams to a PC?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webcam, video-capture

How do I connect two webcams to a PC? I need to grab the frames from the two webcam inputs simultaneously. What software should I use and is there any extra hardware that I will need? I prefer connecting the cameras using USB as most computers have several of these ports. Also please suggest solutions that will work in Linux. I'm using Ubuntu  9.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug the first one in, then plug the second one in. Each will have its own `/dev/videoX` node that can be used for capture. Not sure if there's any prepackaged software for capture though; you might be able to find some ideas in [ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Just plug them in. The kernel will load the driver and create two video devices where you can grab the frames. They won't be in sync 100% so be ready to drop frames every now and then.